# How to get Flux-Results into a set of a Mono-Bean

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, webflux

I have the following scenario: I have a ProductFamily that has a set of Products.

I load the ProduktFamily from the database and then I want to load its Products and insert them into ProduktFamily.products.

Easy in Spring MVC (because of JPA) but with Webflux I am struggeling.
I tried this, but it does not work. ProduktFamily.products-set is empty.

**Service:**

```
public Flux<ProduktfamilyRS> getAllProduktFamilies() {
    return produktfamilyDatabaseFacade.findAll()
        .map(produktfamilyEntity2 -> dtoMapper.produktfamilyEntityToProduktfamilyRS(produktfamilyEntity2)) // <-- Mapsctruct Mapper
        .concatMap(produktfamilyRS -> loadProducts(produktfamilyRS));
  }


private Mono<ProduktfamilieRS> loadProducts(ProduktfamilieRS produktfamilieRS) {
    Flux<ProduktEntity> byProduktfamilieId = produktDatabaseFacade.findByProduktfamilieId(produktfamilieRS.getId());
    Flux<ProduktRS> produktRSFlux = byProduktfamilieId.map(produktEntity -> dtoMapper.produktEntityToProduktRS(produktEntity));

    return Mono.just(produktfamilieRS).map(produktfamilieRS1 -> {
      produktRSFlux.all(produktRS -> produktfamilieRS1.getProdukte().add(produktRS));
      produktRSFlux.subscribe();
      return produktfamilieRS1;
    });
  }
```

**ProduktfamilyDatabaseFacade:**

```
  public Flux<ProduktfamilyEntity> findAll() {
    return produktfamilyRepository.findAll();
  }
```

**ProduktfamilyDatabaseFacade:**

```
 public Flux<ProduktEntity> findByProduktfamilyId(Long produktfamilyId) {
    return produktRepository.findAllByProduktfamilyId(produktfamilyeId)
        .doOnNext(produktEntity -> log.info("Found Produkt '" + produktEntity.getName() + "' für Produktfamilie"));
  }
```

Is there an way to start from the Mono and then iterate through the Flux to add every Product to the Productfamily and then return the ProductfamilyRS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working, but do not know if its a good way. **Can somebody review?**

```
  public Flux<ProduktfamilieRS> getAllProduktFamilien() {
    return produktfamilieDatabaseFacade.findAll()
        .map(produktfamilieEntity2 -> dtoMapper.produktfamilieEntityToProduktfamilieRS(produktfamilieEntity2))
        .concatMap(this::loadProdukteFlat);
  }


  private Mono<ProduktfamilieRS> loadProdukteFlat(ProduktfamilieRS produktfamilieRS) {
    return produktDatabaseFacade.findByProduktfamilieId(produktfamilieRS.getId())
        .doOnNext(produktEntity -> produktfamilieRS.getProdukte().add(dtoMapper.produktEntityToProduktRS(produktEntity)))
        .then(Mono.just(produktfamilieRS));
  }
```

Comment: you can collect all the results to a list or map and then iterate the list and add it to the object and return